# Cannot implicitly convert type System.IServiceProvider to ServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I grab Services from Startup Class in Test Project? Receiving casting error below.

```
        var test = new WebHostBuilder()
           .UseContentRoot("C:\\APITest\\APITest.WebAPI")
           .UseEnvironment("Development")
           .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath("C:\\APITest\\APITest.WebAPI")
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
               .Build())
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .Build();

        ServiceProvider =  test.Services;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IServiceProvider' to
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: It is pretty clear. It will not try to implicitly cast this, but if you are certain of the types just explicitly cast it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your class has ServiceProvider defined as a concrete class. Change it to be defined as the interface.

```
...
// this is wrong
ServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

// this is right
IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) case. There are two kinds of casts, implicit and explicit. Being strongly typed, C# is very conservative with implicit casting. If if was not, we would end up with the [PHP and JavaScript examples from this comic](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/). So it prefers if you decide if you really want to risk a cast.

The message is clear: You have a variable of type `System.IServiceProvider` and try to assign it onto a variable or argument that only takes `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider`. Casting `ServiceProvider` to `IServiceProvider` will happen implicitly. The other way around? Nope.

This is a somewhat odd case - as most Arguments and fields/properties tend to be interfaces or abstract base classes. That way you can be more permissive with what you accept. You rarely see concrete classes used. If this is your code, you propably want to change that. If not, you have to live with risking a explicit cast and hope everything goes well.